# Encrypt the user data without loosing logged in user in android app

Tags: android, c++, encryption, android-ndk

I have an app launched on play store. The app has the signup and sign in process. After sign in application is encrypting the user credentials with [this](https://github.com/fly7632785/KotprefEncryptSupport) library and storing them in shared preferences and also the credentials are decrypted with same library before using the credentials for direct login to the app without entering username and password again and again. But I think this library would not fit my application for encryption and decryption so I found a way for this. I wrote my code in C++ for encryption and decryption and the code is working well. Now I want to add this logic to my existing app and update my app on play store without loosing the previous logged in user. How can I achieve this logic. Any small hint will be appreciated. One of the logic I found was to logout the user if this this version of application is downloaded, but this logic is not satisfied by the client.

Comment: If you do not want to clear the `preferences` then the only way to do this is get all data from `preferences` decrypt it and again save it with new algo . This code must run for only one time for this version of app .

Comment: Ya I and my team were trying to figure out with similar logic but this process will  run every time when  user launch the app.

Comment: Persistent storage can be wipe out manually . You can lower the chances of calling this each time  by saving a `boolean` in `SharePreference`.

Comment: Instead of a `boolean` you might want to store a version, because it is possible that you would want to change the algorithm at some point in the future, and versioning would help you understand whether re-encryption of stored data is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions for you.

1. Add some prefix to the encrypted data during encryption in your encryption method, So that you could figure out if the data is already encrypted or not.
2. During decryption, if the prefix is present in the data that means it is encrypted and you need to decrypt it otherwise you could just proceed further.

***Note: Make you prefix some unique like your package name so that it will have less chance of occurrence in the data saved in pref.***

Comment: i think you misunderstood OP's question

Comment: @TejasPandya,  I think his main problem is to detect weather the values in pref are encrypted by his algorithm or not. So that he could easily detect weather the value should be decrypt with his algorithm or using particular library. That solves his problem of not logging out his users.